# How to retrieve row counts of all tables excluding child tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not sure why second query fails, I'm adding ONLY caluse in second query because i don't need child tables row count.

**SQL WORKING PROPERLY**

```
SELECT count(*) AS rows_cnt 
FROM (
  SELECT pgc.relname 
  FROM pg_class pgc 
  WHERE pgc.oid = 16424 
) as tblname
```

**SQL FACING ISSUE**

```
SELECT count(*) AS rows_cnt 
FROM ONLY ( 
   SELECT pgc.relname 
   FROM pg_class pgc 
   WHERE pgc.oid = 16424 
) as tblname
```

Here "16424" is my Table OID.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my SQL.

**Update on above question:**

```
SELECT count(*) AS rows_cnt 
FROM ONLY "test-1"
```

'test-1' is the table name of oid 16424, and it is working properly, but when I use sub query to generate table name dynamically it fails with below error not sure why.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: (SELECT count(*) AS rows_cnt FROM ONLY ( SELECT pgc.relname ...
                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 42
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Hi , when i hard code the table name (of 16424 oid) in second query it is working fine.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-select.html), the top section seems to use an `ONLY` statement, maybe it's what you need

Comment: @SamSwift웃: please do not link to totally outdated versions. Use `current` instead of the version number in the link

Comment: `select count(*) from "test-1"` is something **completely** than `select count(*) from (select relname from pg_class ...)`. The first one counts the number of rows in `"test-1"` the second one counts the number of tables with that name. Do you happen to mean `select count(*) from only "test-1"`? Maybe you should explain the underlying problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @dnoeth: `FROM ONLY pg_class` won't change a thing as `pg_class` is not an inherited table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  I want to fetch total row count for each tables in my schema and that row count should be of parent table only and not including child tables row count.

Comment: You can't do that with your statement you need dynamic SQL for that. Your query just returns the number of tables, not the number of rows _in_ those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want with static SQL, you need dynamic SQL for this.

The easiest way is to put this into a function:

```
create or replace function get_rowcounts(p_schema text)
  returns table (table_name text, row_count bigint)
as
$$
declare 
   name_rec record;
begin

   for name_rec in select t.table_name
                   from information_schema.tables t
                   where t.table_schema = p_schema
   loop
     return query execute format('select %L::text, count(*) from only %I.%I', name_rec.table_name, p_schema, name_rec.table_name);
   end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

This can be used in the following way:

```
select *
from get_rowcounts('public');
```